# ORACLE APEX PLSQL - LOV LIST, how to have static value as last value in list?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a lov list with an sql query to dynaically fill it in depending on other fields, however, i'd like the last value in the list to be 'Other' no matter what the sql query brings back.

```
select EMP_NAME as d,
       EMP_NAME as r
  from EMP 
  WHERE EMP_NAME = :P09_CAT
 order by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is declarative functionality built in for this common purpose. See just before 13.2.3 http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/managing-page-level-items-in-page-designer.htm#HTMDB29715

Check the "List of Values" set of attributes for the item, specifically "Display null value", "Null Display Value".
Ensure the first is checked, and the latter says 'Other'.

Alternatively, if you want specific data in your LOV you can add a UNION ALL, e.g.:

```
select d, r from (
  select EMP_NAME as d,
         EMP_NAME as r,
         row_number() over (order by emp_name) s
  from EMP 
  WHERE EMP_NAME = :P09_CAT
  union all
  select 'Other','Other',9999999999 from dual
) order by s
```

Answer (score 0):

Create event on page load and use this javascript:

```
var x = document.getElementById("P605_NEW");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Other";
x.add(option);
```

Where my select list is P605_NEW